# "Array to string conversion" error when using hash in Document

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-mongodb

I'm attempting to use the hash type for a Document. When I'm creating an object there isn't a problem, but the moment I attempt to retrieve a document, I get an "Array to string conversion".

I've simplified the document. This Array to string conversion only started occurring when I added this hash property.

Looking at symfony's dump messages, it seems to be coming from the hydrator.

Any ideas why Doctrine is attempting to convert the data to a string?

```
class MyDocument
{
   /**
    * @MongoDB\Id
    */
   protected $id;

   /**
    * @MongoDB\Field(type="hash")
    */
   protected $value = array();

}
```

Somewhere in one of my services:

```
$product = 
  $this->container->get('doctrine_mongodb')
  ->getRepository('XTradBundle:Traduction')
  ->findAll();
```

Stack Trace:

```
in var\cache\dev\doctrine\odm\mongodb\Hydrators\WeBSurgTradBundleDocumentTraductionHydrator.php at line 84   -
     if (isset($data['value']) || (! empty($this->class->fieldMappings['value']['nullable']) && array_key_exists('value', $data))) {
        $value = $data['value'];
        if ($value !== null) {
            //Why is it converting it to a string here?
            $return = (string) $value;
        } else {
            $return = null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would seem that `$value` in `protected $value = array();` is a reserved name. Simply naming it to something else solved the problem.